# Android using BR from another package

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I am trying to access databinding propertyId generated by another package. I get this error:

---

```
D:\Android\TestApp\appbase\src\main\java\com\testapp\appbase\adapters\MenuAdapter.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
        if (propertyId == com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position)
                                                  ^
symbol:   class BR
location: package com.testapp.procallapi
```

---

Here is my code MenuAdapter.java:

```
public void reloadDataSource(ObservableList<CatData> dataSource)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    for (CatData data : dataSource)
    {
        data.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId)
            {
                if (propertyId == com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position)
                {
                    sortItems();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to access **BR** from another package? If I commented the line `if (propertyId == com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position)`, then it compiles and run OK.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(path: ':components')
    compile project(path: ':appdb')
    compile project(path: ':procallapi')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Is it possible to use BR generated by another package? Did I miss anything on my gradle? Any idea?

Thanks...

---

Update

After investigation, I found that I can use the BR on my main application.

Here is the application structured:

```
- com.testapp.procallapi   //contains all my models
- com.testapp.appbaseui    //contains a common UI
- com.testapp.warehouse    //my main application
```

Now, `com.testapp.appbaseui` contains common UIs that will be used for *warehouse* and *retail* user. If I tried to reference the BR (ie. `com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position`) from common ui module **appbaseui** (`com.testapp.appbaseui`) then I get the error.

But if I tried to reference the BR (ie. `com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position`) from main app **warehouse** (`com.testapp.warehouse`), then it will work!

What is it going on here? Any idea? Please help.

---

### Update: Add sample project

I have trimmed down and create a sample project. There will be a lot of unused method as I tried to cut as many as I can. Here is the [Sample Code](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5f184f57bf69a983332cf35089c97fb420170628095046/55cacf8f45094257b9c5a821f2ed935f20170628095046/ff3765).

To replicate the error:

```
1. Simply run the project and you will see the error occurs on appbaseui --> CatListViewAdapter.java (line #94)
2. To make it run, simply disable line #94

Here is the code:
if (propertyId == com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position)  //disable this line to run
{
    reloadCats();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to access the project's BR class. The generated BR is a merged class that will include the IDs generated for all included libraries.

You should be able to access the generated BR class from any included project. Make certain that the library also has data binding enabled in it and the BR package matches the module's declared package. (I can't remember exactly, but I think it is generated under the databinding package). Validate by comparing the package you used in the module import statement.

-- Edit --

You can access any ID from the BR of any library a module depends on, but you must access it from the BR of your own module. You may find the Android Studio doesn't recognize the ID (red underline for the ID), but it will compile. In the example above, change the line:

```
if (propertyId == com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position)
```

to

```
if (propertyId == BR.position)
```

Comment: Hi George, if I don't use `com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position` and only do `BR.position`, it doesn't recognize the **position**. I must use `com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position`. The error only occur when I compile the project. Otherwise, android studio doesn't complain about it. But if I only do `BR.position`, android studio immediately complain: "**cannot resolve symbol 'position'**".

Comment: Hi George, if I use this BR from main application, it worked! But I used this BR inside another package/module. I confirm the project dependencies are OK. Any idea?

Comment: If your library depends on another library's BR id, you must also declare the dependency in the build.gradle file. Other than that, I think it should work (I must verify). Remember that if your library module depends on a library with data binding enabled and needs access to the generated classes (including BR), it must also enable data binding.

Comment: Hi George, I confirm that my library build.gradle does have dependency declared `compile project(path: ':procallapi')`. It also has databinding enabled `dataBinding { enabled = true }` in both my library and main application. I am tearing my hair out here :'(  You are my last hope.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You have just one library module and one application module? And the BR reference works from the application, but not from the library? The library won't be able to reference the application BR class, but that's not what you are trying to do, right?

Comment: Hi George, thanks again for replying. I have updated my question. I hope it becomes clearer. Thank you.

Comment: You can also access the procallapi BR IDs from the BR file generated for appbaseui. I am not sure why you aren't seeing the procallapi BR, but maybe we have a bug there. Try the appbaseui BR and if it works, please file a bug against data binding so that we will remember to fix it.

Comment: Hi George, the error only occur on **compile time**. During the *code writing* process, android studio doesn't detect any error. Only when compile, it complains about `error: cannot find symbol BR`. I've a few local models in `appbaseui` and I can use `com.testapp.appbaseui.BR`. It seems like there is a bug in Android Studio. How to file a bug report?

Comment: I just tried it (back from vacation). You can access the BR file from the current module's BR, but not the included module's BR. So, instead of using  `com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position`, use `com.testapp.appbaseui.BR.position` in the appbaseui module.

Comment: Hi George, welcome back! Thanks again for replying. I've tried `com.testapp.appbaseui.BR.position`, but `com.testapp.appbaseui.BR` doesn't contain **position**. Android studio won't even allow me to compile (ie. error before compile). But if I used `com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position`, Android studio recognized the **position** but failed on the compilation  :(

Comment: Can you provide a very small test app that reproduces the problem? Are you using 3.0 preview or 2.3?

Comment: I just checked with Android Studio 2.3 and it worked there also. I have libraryb depend on librarya and uses one of its BR ids in its code. Both projects have data binding enabled. I tried using BR ids from both a model (@Bindable) and from layout (variable declaration) and they both work. Are you using kotlin? There may be a compilation order issue there that we haven't explored.

Comment: Hi George, I'll make a project and will post it here. It is nearly 1am. time to go to bed. lol... :D  thank you so so much, I'll cut down my project and post it here tomorrow :)

Comment: Hi George, I have attached the link to the sample project. Thanks again for looking into this.

Comment: I had to reset the dates on the files because they are in my timezone's future. I then changed the line `if (propertyId == com.testapp.procallapi.BR.position)` to `if (propertyId == BR.position)`. The BR.position shows red. I also cleaned the project, but I don't know if that mattered. It compiled and ran fine.

Comment: Wooohooaaaa!!! George!!! Mate! I owed you a lunch! It worked. Even though Android studio shows red on it. Can you posted your answer (your last comment)? I will accept your answer (and you must CLEAN the project, otherwise, you'll get compilation error). How to report this bug to Android Studio team? Is it possible to report bug here?

Comment: You can file a bug by clicking on "Help > Submit Feedback" in Android Studio.

Comment: Done! Thanks again George.